# Corona SDK: Convert local Sqlite database to Json string then use Php to add to database

Tags: php, json, sqlite, lua, coronasdk

### I have a lua file that looks like this:

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

-- Add onscreen text
local label1 = display.newText( "SQLite demo", 20, 30, native.systemFontBold, 60 )
label1:setTextColor( 190, 190, 255 )
local label2 = display.newText( "Creates or opens a local database", 20, 100, native.systemFont, 40 )
label2:setTextColor( 190, 190, 255 )
local label3 = display.newText( "(Data is shown below)", 20, 140, native.systemFont, 40 )
label3:setTextColor( 255, 255, 190 )

--Include sqlite
require "sqlite3"
--Open data.db.  If the file doesn't exist it will be created
local path = system.pathForFile("data.db", system.DocumentsDirectory)
db = sqlite3.open( path )

--Handle the applicationExit event to close the db
local function onSystemEvent( event )
        if( event.type == "applicationExit" ) then
            db:close()
        end
end

--Setup the table if it doesn't exist
local tablesetup = [[CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (content, content2);]]
print(tablesetup)
db:exec( tablesetup )

--Add rows with a auto index in 'id'. You don't need to specify a set of values because we're populating all of them
testvalue = {2}
local id = system.getInfo("deviceID")
testvalue[1] = id
local time_stamp = os.time()
testvalue[2] = time_stamp


local tablefill =[[INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, ']]..testvalue[1]..[[',']]..testvalue[2]..[['); ]]

db:exec( tablefill )


--print the sqlite version to the terminal
print( "version " .. sqlite3.version() )

--print all the table contents
for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM test") do
  local text = row.content.." "..row.content2
  local t = display.newText(text, 20, 160 + (60 * row.id), native.systemFont, 40)
  t:setTextColor(255,0,255)
end

--setup the system listener to catch applicationExit
Runtime:addEventListener( "system", onSystemEvent )
```

---

All this does is store the unique id of the device and a time stamp in a local sqlite database. I need to take this information and put it in a json string. I also have a simple localhost database called 'testdata' with two columns; 'id' & 'time'. I need to take my json string and use a php file to insert the information into my database.

I have no experience with php so I'm finding it difficult.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Rob Miracle, I managed to figure it out by doing it a whole different why to what I described. Those links would have been great a week ago! Cheers anyway. They should come in handy in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post might be of value for you:

http://omnigeek.robmiracle.com/2012/04/15/using-corona-sdk-with-rest-api-services/

Also this week's Corona Geek went over this in some detail:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4J9A6M3Ii-A